# PHP when refresh page ,browser remove a session

Tags: php, session, refresh

I don't know exactly how to explain ...
When I log in, on a browser page, enter the correct user, but if I open another page, still in the browser in use, and I refresh it automatically chooses one of the two users, deleting the other

I don't know if I have explained myself well, I don't know how to explain myself well. excuse me

This is a private page code (page after log in)

```
session_start();


function authenticate()
{
    return array_key_exists('email', $_SESSION);
};

if (authenticate() !== true) {
  header("location: /private/login/log-in.php");
} 

$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];

$check_id = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $check_id);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  $fetch_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $user_id = $fetch_info['id'];
};


   This is a login code

session_start();

$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];

$check_id = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $check_id);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  $fetch_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
};

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
  $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
  $password = md5($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $sql_insert_date = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE usertable SET activeLogInDate = '$date'");
  $check_email = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email' ";
  $res = mysqli_query($conn, $check_email);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    $_SESSION['id'] = $fetch['id'];
    $uniqueID = $fetch['uniqueID'];
    $username = $fetch['username'];
    $name = $fetch['name'];
    $fetch_pass = $fetch['password'];
    if (password_verify($password, $fetch_pass)) {
      $activeStatus = "Online";
      $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE usertable SET activeStatus = '$activeStatus'");
      $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
      $status = $fetch['status'];
      if ($status == 'verified') {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        header("location: /private/private_page/private.php?us=$uniqueID?nm=$username");
      } else {
        $info = "Non è stata verificata la tua identità,controlla il messaggio inviato all' email $email";
        $_SESSION['info'] = $info;
        header('location: /private/otp/otp-code.php');
      }
    } else {
      $errors['email'] = "Inserimento password o email non corretto!";
    }
  } else {
    $errors['email'] = "Sembra che tu non sia ancora un membro! Clicca sul pulsante registrati per iscriverti.";
  }
};
```

Comment: Please share some of your codes.. have you started the session with session_start()?

Comment: Where is your login code? I mean where do you set those values in session?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Are you trying to login using 2 different users on the same browsers on 2 different tabs? If so then, the browser share session across tabs. So when you login using a different user on a new tab and then go back to the first tab and refresh it, now the first tab will have the same session as the second tab.

Comment: correct ! thanks! how can I fix the error, so as to have more users active on the same browser?

Comment: That is not possible Andrea. That is how browser works. Unfortunate we cannot do anything there.. For you can check any website.. for example stackoverflow.. If you open another tab and try to login with another user and then go to the previous tab and refresh it, it will change as well (to the newly logged in user on the 2nd tab)

Comment: Thank you so much! for the answer, I thought I was wrong, thank you very much again Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

The line -

```
$password = md5($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

is incorrect.  md5()'s second parameter is meant to be a bool; you've got a likely copy/paste/edit error from the previous line, filter_var();

Take out the second parameter.

BTW you shouldn't really rely on md5 these days.  There's a [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)() function that's what you should be using now.